# How can I allow non-admin users to manage tags?

Tags: permissions, acl, tags

I have a Drupal role which I have given the permission `CiviCRM: administer Tagsets` and `CiviCRM: administer reserved tags` but not `CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM`.

They still get access denied when visiting `/civicrm/admin/tag?reset=1`.

I do not want to give them `CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug already reported at  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15371.

Managing tags needs its own permission rather than requiring "administer CiviCRM" permission. Anyone interested in getting started on core programming will likely find this a good one to begin with.

Comment: Accurate guess: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29969.0

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback useful to me and others. Could you also mark my answer as accepted? Cheers!

Comment: I incorporated your comment into Answer. Cheers.